# Null properties in RequestScope bean in Spring Boot and Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Spring Boot 2.7.2
Kotlin: 221-1.7.10-release-333-IJ5591.52

```
@SpringBootApplication
class AbcApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<AbcApplication>(*args)
}

@RestController
class Home(val importantContext: ImportantContext) {


    @GetMapping
    fun index(): Any {
        return "toString: '${importantContext}' VS message: '${importantContext.importantMessage}'";
    }
}

@Configuration
class ImportantConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    fun importantContext(): ImportantContext {
        return ImportantContext("important content")
    }

}

open class ImportantContext(var importantMessage: String?) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "ImportantContext(importantMessage=$importantMessage)"
    }
}
```

Calling GET http://localhost:8080 returns *toString: 'ImportantContext(importantMessage=important content)' VS message: 'null'*
where I would expect message to be the same, not null. Maybe it is some proxy related issue. I'm not that good in Kotlin yet to figure this out by myself.

**EDIT1**
I rewrote ImportantContext in Java and it works correctly (importantMessage field actually has value assigned). Question remains, why it does not work in Kotlin?